# Can two people be logged into the same psn plus account at the same time and play different games online?

Tags: ps4, psn

Can two ps4's (one mine and one my friends) share the same psn plus?

For example, if I buy psn plus set it up with my account. Then can he log into my account on HIS PS4 and play online at the same time as I do if we play different games? Like if I'm playing COD online can he be playing FIFA if we both are logged into the same account on our respective ps4?

Comment: you need to do the make your friends ps4 your primary trick. and he has to use his own account to play and you use yours

Answer (score 4):

No, this isn't possible. The moment the second person logged into the same account, the first person would be forcibly logged out.

This has happened to me with my friends who have PS4s I've logged into in the past. It will kick your friend offline even if you're not playing online, too. (I was kicked out of a Dark Souls III boss when my friend was trying to do local multiplayer with a friend in Rocket League with my account)

Comment: Does it just kick you offline or does it prevent you from playing games in SP as well?